# add blank for 0 result into existing formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

is there any way to use this formula [<30,0,1)) for a group of cells in Sheet1!(A14:I100)] and if result == 0 insert blank or add [=IF(O16=0,"",] somehow so all 0 results just show a blank result. I'm just not sure how to add this to my formula

so if Cell a176= 07:48:16 and formula [<30,0,1)) for a group of cells in Sheet1!(A14:I100)] changes it to 468, all is good - however if Cell a176= 00:00:16, the result is "0" - I would like the result to be "" blank "" instead of "0".

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 0's to display as blank:

```
On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the View tab.
Do one of the following:
    To display zero (0) values in cells, select the Zero values check box.
    To display zero values as blank cells, clear the check box.
```

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-or-hide-zero-values-HP005199879.aspx

Comment: so no way just to add it to the calculation? some 0's are needed - others need to be blank

Comment: @Tom =if(yourformula=0,"",yourformula)